# Creating a folder with the same name as a controller results in 404 - Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2

If one creates a root level folder with the same name/route as a controller IIS seems to try and route to the folder and not consult the WebAPI 2 routing.

**Example:**

```
ProjectA
|- Controllers/
|-- ExamplesController.cs
|- Examples/
```

**ExamplesController**

```
[RoutePrefix("examples")]
public class ExamplesController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
   {
    // code
   }
}
```

The expectation is that hit the controller, however IIS seems to try and browse the folder instead.

Example: `http://localhost:123/examples`

**Attempted Solutions:**

I've tried to play around the IIS Handlers to see if I can remove all other handlers but that didn't help

Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing system checks the file system to see if a URL matches a file/folder on the disk. If it finds a match, the routing is ignored and the request bypassed any route entries so that the file will be served directly. This is there so that static files are served without going through MVC Routing

To change this behavior you can set the RouteExistingFiles property to true in your RouteConfig, however this may impact your static files, so do test them thoroughly

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: Perfect, will give this a try and mark it as the answer if it does work as described

Comment: Did you try this ? Any issues ?

Comment: This worked as expected but only because we don't serve any static content from our API. Could get more tricky if you needed to serve have both extensionless routing and static content.